# How to create controller for data in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is the current code I have for the model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Courses extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'courses';

    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        echo $course->course;
    }
}
```

Is this coded correctly?  The data is being fetched from the 'courses' table and 'courses' is the name of the column.

I am adding a new feature to my search directory. The profiles contain variables from the database so there is a lot of data being fetched from the same database table. There is one data, however, that is being put into a separate table because it can't fit in the same table as the other data.  So I have to figure out a way to fetch that data from the other database table and put it into the profile code.

Here is the controller for the profile page (the snippet that controls the view):

```
//view school
public function viewschool ($url){
   $url ='schools/' . $url;
    if (count(School::where('url', '=', $url)->first()) <> 1 ) {
        return redirect()->back();
    }

    $sch = School::where('url', '=', $url)->first();
    $articles = posts::where('post_type','article')->where('school',$sch->name)->take(3)->get();
    $news = posts::where('post_type','news')->where('school',$sch->name)->take(3)->get();
    $others = posts::where('post_type','news')->take(3)->get();

    return view('school-info')
        ->with(array('sch' => $sch,'school_articles' => $articles,'school_news' => $news,'others' => $others));
}
```

The new data are the school courses. the database table for courses contain columns for school ID (basically the courses are matched up to the ID of the school name they belong to in the schools table) as well as other data such as duration of course and tuition.

Am wondering how do I create the controller code for the school courses?

Comment: `count(School::where('url', '=', $url)->first())` Is this check supposed to handle more than 1? Also, you're running the same `School::where('url', '=', $url)->first()` twice... Don't repeat yourself. Could do `$school = School::where('url', '=', $url)->first();` ... `if(!$school){ return back(); }`

Comment: It handles the school listings page where more than 1 school show up and it handles the school profile page where only 1 school is displayed.

Comment: Even if there are multiple schools with the same `$url`, `->first()` will only return one (the first based on default sorting), so `count(...)` will only ever been 1 or 0, nothing different.

Comment: this is what it looks like on the site https://collegeconnect.ph/schools

Comment: @kenken9999 I learn by doing, not by reading.  I can read any article about Laravel but I'll never learn unless I see the the right code in action and then I can understand how it works and the article will make better sense.

Answer (score 1):

So first improve your understanding of the Model in Laravel. You just define the properties for your classes there. The `foreach` is totally out of place there.

An example Model should look like this:

```
<?php
 namespace App;

 use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

 class Course extends Model 
 {

 protected $table = 'courses';

 protected $fillable = ['properties'];

 }
```

So you would've start with a "fresh" and ready to use Model. Every Action with your Model you do inside your Controller. But DB Queries you do inside a Repository.

And now regarding your Question:

You can define relationships within Models via e.g.

```
protected $searchable = 
[
     'relations' => [
            'schools' => [
                  'foreignKey' => 'school_id',
                  'foreignField' => 'courses'
                          ]
                     ]
]
```

Edit: forgot the method inside the model :D

```
public function schools(): BelongsTo
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Schools::class);
}
```

Comment: I've edited the model so it only contains `protected $table = 'courses';` in between the brackets.  I finally got the code in the controller to work, but now I have a problem.  One school can be in multiple rows because it has different majors.  So if "School A" has one course with 6 different majors, that one course will be seen 6 different times with each major.  So....6 rows of data.  How would I edit the model so that all the majors can be displayed in the frontend under one school?  Instead of the course showing up 6 times in the school profile, it should show up once with the 6 majors.

Comment: The column for the majors is 'major' and the column for the course names is 'course'.

Comment: Just intercept this inside your controller via checking if property A is already displayed/set and modify your output there